# SQL server 2005 agent not working

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, sql-server-agent

Sql server 2005  service pack 2 version: 9.00.3042.00

All maintenance plans fail with the same error.

The details of the error are:-

---

Execute Maintenance Plan

- Execute maintenance plan. test7 (Error)
  Messages
  Execution failed. See the maintenance plan and SQL Server Agent job history logs for details.

The advanced information section shows the following;

### Job 'test7.Subplan_1' failed. (SqlManagerUI)

Program Location:
at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlManagerUI.MaintenancePlanMenu_Run.PerformActions()

At this point the following appear in the windows event log:
Event Type: Error
Event Source:   SQLISPackage
Event Category: None
Event ID:   12291
Date:       28/05/2009
Time:       16:09:08
User:       'DOMAINNAME\username'
Computer:   SQLSERVER4
Description:
Package "test7" failed.

## and also this:

Event Type: Warning
Event Source:   SQLSERVERAGENT
Event Category: Job Engine 
Event ID:   208
Date:       28/05/2009
Time:       16:09:10
User:       N/A
Computer:   SQLSERVER4
Description:

### SQL Server Scheduled Job 'test7.Subplan_1' (0x96AE7493BFF39F4FBBAE034AB6DA1C1F) - Status: Failed - Invoked on: 2009-05-28 16:09:02 - Message: The job failed.  The Job was invoked by User 'DOMAINNAME\username'.  The last step to run was step 1 (Subplan_1).

There are no entries in the SQl Agent log at all.

Comment: Did you pull the error info from the failed step in the history?  Scroll down in the viewer... this is where I typically find the best info.

Answer (score 1):

Probably no points for this, but you're likely to get more help on this over at ServerFault.com now that they are open.