# SQL Server Agent not running

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-agent, sql-job

None of the SQL Jobs on my server are running. I've looked into this and got the message:

```
SQLServerAgent is not currently running so it cannot be notified of this action
```

How can I get SQL Server Agent to start running on SQL Server 2008?

Comment: Did you try starting the service?

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL server 2005 agent not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/921469/sql-server-2005-agent-not-working)

Comment: you should be able to delete the question yourself (I think)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

`net start SQLSERVERAGENT` (for default instance, or just use services.msc or SQL Server Configuration Manager)